# Hazelcast load from data store or recovery from replica

Tags: hazelcast

When starting a Hazelcast cluster instance, how can i decide whether i should pre-populate from data store or to rely on cluster auto recover from replica?

if every instance always loads at startup, that will cause to much dup workload?

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

Hazelcast is in-memory data grid. With the default configuration, it doesn't touch a disk or RBMS.
However, you can implement [`MapLoader`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#map-persistence) to prepopulate Hazelcast from a database of your choice.
You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/mapstore)

**p.s.** you shouldn't worry about duplicate workload. Hazelcast will spread the keys of a map across member nodes, and the corresponding member will load data by this key.

Comment: Could you provide example how populate hazelcast from postures table with more than 20 millions rows?